# Why ReactJS update state isn't working as expected?

Tags: reactjs, state

I know this question was asked before. But if I follow the accepted answer it doesn't work for me. Here is my code:-

```
  export class SurveyForm extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isSelected: false,
    selectedVal: 0,
    selectedRatingIndex: -1,
  };
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

onClick={() => {
      // this is the recommended way of setting state. This doesn't work. 
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        selectedRatingIndex: (prevState.selectedRatingIndex = val),
      }));

      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        isSelected: (prevState.isSelected = !this.state.isSelected),
      }));
// other code removed.  
}
```

But if I do as follows:-

```
     this.setState({
        selectedRatingIndex: (this.state.selectedRatingIndex = val),
      });
      this.setState({
        isSelected: (this.state.isSelected = !this.state.isSelected),
      });
```

It works and it shows the warning `Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()` I am confused, what should one do in this case?

Comment: Where does variable val come from?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setState` with an object,  that object should just contain the new values.

```
this.setState({
    selectedRatingIndex: val,
});
this.setState({
    isSelected: !this.state.isSelected, // it would be better to use a prevState callback instead of this.state
});
```

When you use a `prevState` callback, you return an object of new values derived from `prevState`.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
    selectedRatingIndex: val, // there is no point to a prevState callback here because prevState is unused
}));
this.setState(prevState => ({
    isSelected: !prevState.isSelected,
}));
```

---

When you do something like this:

```
this.setState({
    selectedRatingIndex: (this.state.selectedRatingIndex = val),
});
```

You are mutating the state by setting `this.state.selectedRatingIndex = val` with `=` which is the assignment operator.  The returned value from that assignment is the new value (`val`) so that's why it kinda-sorta works: you *are* essentially calling `this.setState({ selectedRatingIndex: val })`, but you're mutating the state in the process which you should not do.